# Open MsgBox if a date on birthday list matches today

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I try and execute my code it says "object required."

I want a MsgBox to open if one a date on my birthday list matches today.

The birthday list extends from b2 to b100 and I want to look through to find the birthday.

This is a piece of code I took from a YouTube video.

The MsgBox pops up every time I open the workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim cl As Range
    Set cl = ThisWorbook.Sheets("Birthdays").Range("B2:B100")
    If IsDate(cl) Then
        If Now >= cl Then
            MsgBox "Somebody's had a birthday!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't test a single value against and range array.  You will need to loop the range and test each one.

Comment: Even if I state the range as just B2 it still won't execute

Comment: `cl` is a range, not a value. try `IsDate(cl.value)` (assuming `cl` is a single cell)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that just makes the implicit member call explicit though. I'd be surprised if it changed anything.

Comment: You are getting Object Required error because of a typo ThisWorbook should be ThisWorkbook

Answer (score 3):

You are getting **Object Required** error because of a typo `ThisWorbook` should be `ThisWorkbook`

It is very normal to encounter such errors. So always use `Option Explicit`. I have covered it in [To ‘Err’ is Human](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2017/12/15/to-err-is-human/)

**So Can I have it added to my code automatically?**

Yes you can. To have it added to all new files you create, simply select "Tools" -> "Options" in the VBE, and tick the "Require Variable Declaration" box.

Note: This will effect only new files that you create. You will need to add it yourself to existing files.

> I basically just want my excel to create a msgbox when I open it, if one of the date on my birthday list matches today.

You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check if there is today's date in a range.

```
Sub Sample() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim matchFound As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Birthdays")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B100")

    matchFound = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Date)

    If matchFound > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Birthday Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Birthday Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: AAAAAAAH dammit, of course it was a typo!! Good eye! Now might be a good time to mention `Option Explicit` ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

`cl` is a `Range` object representing 99 <s>dalmatians</s> cells, each encapsulating a `Variant` value.

The `IsDate` function is happy to take *a* `Variant`, but doesn't know what to do with 99 of them.

Because `Range` has a hidden *default property*, you *can* use it as if it were a value - but, especially for someone that's just beginning to learn VBA, it makes for confusing, implicit, "magic" code that *says one thing, and does another*.

```
If IsDate(cl.Value) Then
```

The implicit `Range.Value` member call here, yields a `Variant` representing the cell's value itself *if the range represents only a single cell*, otherwise (i.e. if the range is for more than one cell) it yields a `Variant` pointing to a 2D `Variant` array (in this case 99x1) that's holding *every single value*.

`IsDate` wants *one* value, so if we have 99 of them, we need a loop. But here's the thing: the last thing we want to do is iterate individual cells, get their `Value`, and verify that - because that would be very slow.

So instead, we grab that 2D `Variant` array, and iterate *that*.

```
If cl.Count = 1 Then
    'single-cell range: not a 2D array 
    If Now >= cl.Value Then
        MsgBox "Somebody's had a birthday on " & Format(cl.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim values As Variant
values = cl.Value

Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = LBound(values, 1) To UBound(values, 1)
    Dim currentCol As Long
    For currentCol = LBound(values, 2) To UBound(values, 2)
        Dim currentValue As Variant
        currentValue = values(currentRow, currentCol)
        If IsDate(currentValue) Then
            If Now >= currentValue Then
                MsgBox "Somebody's had a birthday on " & Format(currentValue, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

---

> *Right now the msgbox just pops up every time I open the excel whether a birthday matches or not.*

Sounds like your actual code has `On Error Resume Next` somewhere - that makes VBA *ignore* any run-time errors and merrily keep running, ...and you definitely don't want that. Rule of thumb, never use `On Error Resume Next` to side-step an error. Execution is normally halted when there's an "object required" error: an unconditional `MsgBox` popping means execution is allowed to continue in an error state, and that can't be a good thing.

[As Sid found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910629/object-required-code-wont-execute-in-my-excel/57910967#comment102241604_57910629), the *type mismatch* is caused by a typo -- this shouldn't be allowed to happen: make sure every module you ever type any code in says `Option Explicit` at the top, and it'll never happen again... for your early-bound code (late-bound code is still vulnerable to typos, but that's another story for another time).

Lastly, note that several of the above mentioned issues would have been reported by [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/)'s code inspections (disclaimer: I manage this open-source project) - including the typo, the implicit default member calls, and the absence of `Option Explicit`.